# Drawing of 2D matrix/heatmap

Tags: matrix, three.js, 2d, visualization, data-visualization

I'm relatively new to three.js but I get everything up and running. I want to misuse three.js for a 2d visualization.

Now my question: I want to draw matrices as big as possible in this form: http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/network_correlations.html
Maybe I even need something more sophisticated in the cells of the matrix.

However there are just too many choices how to design this in three.js. Should I use plain boxes, planes or sprites?Should I dig into the particle system? Is there something I missed? What are the advantages and disadvantages of the choices?

I know this is an open question, but what interests me is a) performance = size of the matrix and b) interactions/modification possibilities = change the ordering of the rows and columns + change the width of some of the rows and columns.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you found any answers?  facing the same thing here...

Comment: Nope... No answers, yet. + I had no time to follow up on that